# $anchorScroll invokes route

Tags: angularjs

I just want to scroll to an element which is on the same page but when I use $anchorScroll service it invokes the route, this is what I have in the controller:

```
BIControllers.controller('ParentCtrl',['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll', 
function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll, DataService) {

    $scope.showInformation = function () {

        $location.hash('Info');

        $anchorScroll();

    };

}]);
```

and this is the anchor tag:

```
<a ng-click="showInformation()">Info</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a ng-click="showInformation()" id="Info">Info</a>
```

use it. here you need to use id attr to identify through javascript.

Comment: the element I want to navigate to is <div id="Info">...</div>